# Python pandas - year into datetime error

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to get a year (1980) into a `datetime` column in pandas, but I'm getting an error. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(r'd:\downloads\googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-a', sep='\t', 
                                                            header=None, \
        names=["word","year","occurred","books"], \
        dtype={"word":"str","year":"datetime","occured":"int64","books":"int64"},
                parse_dates=True)
df.head()
```

The error is

```
TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a well-documented bug, the suggestion I can give now is to:

1. Remove `dtype` from `pd.read_csv()`.
   -> `read_csv()` automatically infers the data type of the columns,
2. Do `df.dtypes` to ensure you have your preferred datatypes.

Now, to explicitly convert the column `year` to `datetime`, you can use the method `pd.to_datetime`. For example:

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'])
```

Comment: Still getting the exact same error after doing that.

Comment: try `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the datetime package